# Hosts with IP range

Tags: ansible

I have hosts without stable hostnames, but with predefined IP ranges.
How can I set the IP range for Ansible inventory file?

I'm trying to setup something like this:

*test.ini*:

```ini
[database]
db ansible_ssh_host=1.1.1.[20:25] ansible_ssh_port=22
[lemp]
lemp ansible_ssh_host=1.1.1.[10:15] ansible_ssh_port=22
```

And now I get this error after running `ansible-playbook -i test.ini`:

> fatal: [db] => SSH Error: ssh: Could not resolve hostname 1.1.1.[20:25]: Name or service not known

Comment: note you can write a script that generates your "hosts file".

Comment: Yes, but in my case, I wrote a bash script that can parce inventory files. It can automatically get ssh fingerprints (and keys) for my virtual containers.
And when I made a mistake with IP ranges in ansible_ssh_host variables, I was a little bit confused =)
But now I found write format (listed below) and changed my script.
(Sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found this working solution for my problem:

*test.ini*:

```ini
# I removed hostname section and ansible_ssh_host=
10.0.3.[20:25] ansible_ssh_port=22
```