# Ansible Playbook: I want to use ip address range in "hosts"

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

Ansible Playbook: I want to use ip address **range** in "hosts".

I want to execute the playbook from 10.134.10.**1** to 10.134.10.**99** IP Range. i.e 10.134.10.[1-99].

I tried with below, but it did not worked.

```
- name: Adhoc Commands
  hosts: "10.134.10.1-99"
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
     - name: running multiple commands
       ios_command:
        commands: "{{ item }}"
       with_items: "{{ commandList }}"
       register: output
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hosts with IP range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33648627/hosts-with-ip-range)

Comment: Try to modify **"10.134.10.1-99"** with **"10.134.10.[1:99]"**

Comment: @MedAnoirBday: no, this is how you define a range of hosts in an inventory, not a pattern with which you can target hosts in a play.

Answer (score 2):

Do not confuse [ranges to declare different hosts in your inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#adding-ranges-of-hosts) with [patterns you use to target hosts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html) which can eventually use a regex in which you can define (kind of) a range.

The following example demonstrates both concepts.

First let's define an inventory (fake for the example) in which we will include 2 entire networks including the one you target in your example

```yaml
all:
  vars:
    ansible_connection: local
  hosts:
    10.134.1[0:1].[1:254]:
```

Then a playbook in which we will target only the host in the range you want to reach.

```yaml
---
- hosts: ~^10\.134\.10\.[0-9]$, ~^10\.134\.10\.[0-9][0-9]$
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "I'm running on {{ inventory_hostname }}"
```